# Preventing concurrent access to documents in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My server application (using node.js, mongodb, mongoose) has a collection of documents for which it is important that two client applications cannot modify them at the same time without seeing each other's modification.

To prevent this I added a simple document versioning system: a pre-hook on the schema which checks if the version of the document is valid (i.e., not higher than the one the client last read). At first sight it works fine:

```
// Validate version number
UserSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  var user = this

  user.constructor.findById(user._id, function(err, userCurrent) { // userCurrent is the user that is currently in the db
    if (err) return next(err)
    if (userCurrent == null) return next()

    if(userCurrent.docVersion > user.docVersion) {
      return next(new Error("document was modified by someone else"))
    } else {
      user.docVersion = user.docVersion + 1
      return next()
    }
  })
})
```

The problem is the following:

When one User document is saved at the same time by two client applications, is it possible that these interleave between the pre-hook and the actual save operations? What I mean is the following, imagine time going from left to right and v being the version number (which is persisted by save):

```
App1:  findById(pre)[v:1]                                   save[v->2]
App2:                      findById(pre)[v:1]   save[v->2]
```

Resulting in App1 saving something that has been modified meanwhile (by App2), and it has no way to notice that it was modified. App2's update is completely lost.

My question might boil down to: Do the Mongoose pre-hook and the save method happen in one atomic step?

If not, could you give me a suggestion on how to fix this problem so that no update ever gets lost?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MongoDB has [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) which, for a single matching document, is an atomic operation.

Mongoose has various methods that use this method, and I think that they will suit your use case:

- [`Model.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)
- [`Model.findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)
- [`Model.findOneAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove)
- [`Model.findByIdAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove)

Another solution (one that Mongoose itself uses as well for its [own document versioning](http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943525537/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning)) is to use the [*Update Document if Current*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-if-current/) pattern.

Comment: Thank you, that works. Especially the pattern you suggested since it allows for document version checking before attempting to update.

Comment: is there a library that does this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-update-if-current seems outdated and only works on save

Comment: @olawalejuwonm have you read this? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey

Comment: @robertklepYes. Thank you